PHARO. Deberá retornar true en caso de que exista dentro de la colección algún envío para ese mes especificado, y cuando lo ejecuto me sale todo false
existeEnvioParaMes: mes anio: anio
|subCollection |
envios isNotEmpty ifTrue: [ 
subCollection := envios select: [ :envio | envio mes = mes ].
subCollection := subCollection select: [ :envio | envio anio = anio ].
^subCollection notEmpty].

^false
esta es la consigna. 

"existeEnvioParaMes: anio: debe retornar true o false según corresponda. Deberá retornar true en caso de que exista dentro de la colección algún envío para ese mes especificado como primer colaborador y para ese año especificado como segundo colaborador. Deberá retornar false, en caso de no existir ningún envío para ese mes y año especificados como colaboradores." PORGRAME EN PHARO, SMALLTALK
y asi lo hice en playground
empresa := Empresa new.
envio1 := Envio new.
envio1 mes: 6; anio: '2024'; addHojaRuta: ruta1.
envio1 mes: 7; anio: '2024'; addHojaRuta: ruta2.
envio1 mes: 8; anio: '2024'; addHojaRuta: ruta3.
envio1 mes: 9; anio: '2024'; addHojaRuta: ruta4.
envio1 mes: 9; anio: '2024'; addHojaRuta: ruta5.
empresa addenvios: envio1 .
Transcript show: 'Existe envío en Junio 2024: ', (empresa existeEnvioParaMes: 6 anio: 2024) asString; cr.
Transcript show: 'Existe envío en Julio 2024: ', (empresa existeEnvioParaMes: 7 anio: 2024) asString; cr.
Transcript show: 'Existe envío en Agosto 2024: ', (empresa existeEnvioParaMes: 8 anio: 2024) asString; cr.
Transcript show: 'Existe envío en Septiembre 2024: ', (empresa existeEnvioParaMes: 9 anio: 2024) asString; cr.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
